# Get the alt attribute from an image and add it as a class to the same image

Tags: jquery, attr

I'm trying to get the alt attribute from each of the images in a gallery and then add that text as a class to that same image.

I have tried this so far:

```
(document).ready(function(){

    var $grid = $('.gallery').imagesLoaded( function() {

    console.log ($(".gallery-item").length);
    // I get 14, the number of images in my gallery.

    $(".gallery-item").each(function() {
         var alt = $(this).attr( "alt" );
         console.log(alt);
         // I get 14 undefineds
         $(this).addClass(alt);
});
```

Comment: add html markup

Comment: Please inlcude your html

Comment: If what you have in the alt attribute actually makes sense as class names - then it most likely did not make sense as the content of the alt attribute in the first place.

Comment: My guess would be that it is _not_ the images themselves that have the class `gallery-item`, but probably a wrapping container element ...

Comment: If this piece of code is supposed to be complete then there are a few issues with it.

You're missing `$` at the start and both anonymous functions are never closed, so there's two pieces of `});` missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
var alt = $(this).find("img").attr("alt");

$(this).addClass(alt);
```

Comment: Yep that was it, I was trying to get the alt from the wrap instead of the actual image, thank you. Accepting when it allows me.

Comment: @Sergi Do you understand why its important now to add your html also, people could then have told you what the problem was asap

Comment: It's a Wordpress Gallery, the HTML is generated by Wordpress, that's why I needed some solution like this because the HTML is obviously not accessible, otherwise I'd just put the class there.

Answer (score -1):

`alt` attribute is not mandatory, so is possible that some `img` does not have it. If you can post your HTML I am sure we  can be more usefull.

Anyway the real problem is that the `alt` attribute can contain characters that are not allowed or that can create some problems if used as classes. For example `alt` can contain spaces but that means 2 classes in `class` attribute ( for example "image of a ball" as alt results in 4 classes if you put this text in class attribute )

So if you want to do that I suggest you to replace at least all spaces with some character ("-" or "_" could be ok).